# SMPS Vcc is not generating

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I am working on 12V 30A smps that has only 1V output. I haven't got board's schematic but I found one same like mine ([Schematic Link](http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20151028_smps_variable_voltage/s-400-12_supply.pdf)).

- I measured high voltage capacitors (C2 and C3 on the schematic.) and bridge rectifier. They are working.
- Also checked power switching transistor on board they seem fine. (Q1 and Q4 on the schematic.)
- Checked PWM transistors on board. They also fine. (Q2 and Q3 on the schematic.)
- I measured PWM IC's Vcc pin(pin12) and it is 2.4V.

I think, there could be a problem with D12 and D11 but not checked( because they are located under transformer).

Also [on this link](http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20151028_smps_variable_voltage/), the author says this circuit has the self-starting capability. After I read it, I become suspicious of C10 also.

> Update1: I checked D12 and D11 both working. I read 110V DC over C10(Input 220V AC)

I attached pictures both front and back.

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How is Vcc generated for startup before switching? I can not see it in the schematic.

Comment: @winny I am not sure but it is called as self-starting. Capacitor on the input (C10 on schematic) somehow resonates the voltage then aux winding start to generate Vcc. That is all I understand from [this link](http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20151028_smps_variable_voltage/).

Comment: @winny Vcc is not being generated before startup. Instead, one transistor is getting triggered (through the input's positive rail) just before the other one. So the first switching action is initiated without the need of 494 -- just like in an RCC. But one thing that caught my eye is that the circuit is not isolated and how V- is connected to the input's negative rail is not shown.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I haven't got enough experience on hardware so probably I missed. I think that the dotted primer pin of TR2 is negative rail of the primer and isn't that isolated?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Excellent spotted! It's a subclass of predominantly Chinese power supplies not taught in school.

Comment: @EmreAnılTERZİOĞLU In that case, you only have one shot at building up Vcc on that first self-trigger. Miss it and you will stall it. Can you capture the Vcc during start-up? How are you powering it? It's a stretch, but say ramping up the voltage via VARIAC could cause an issue here.

Comment: @winny It's connected directly to 220V outlet. To capture Vcc, I haven't got oscilloscope so can't I guess. Which component can cause this situation on board? I can check it.

Comment: Troubleshooting an SMPS without a scope is near impossible. Please get one. Since you do have output, I would expect some kind of hick-up mode. Shorted diode somewhere?

Comment: @EmreAnılTERZİOĞLU IC1's GND and output's GND are shorted (They are all connected to V-). So the output is not isolated from mains.

Comment: Since the Vcc does not build up as the circuit cannot start, there's a lot of things to check: 1) You can start from checking that C2 and C3 are okay *(also the voltage across them should be around 160VDC)*. 2) Check Q1, Q4, and their surrounding components as the circuit starts itself independently of the TL494. 3) If at least one of D12 and D11 is somehow shorted then the Vcc pin will be shorted to V-, which means Vcc will never build up. 4) If C12 is shorted then it'll short the Vcc to V-. 5) If the output is shorted then the circuit can't start. 6) Check TL494's outputs are not shorted.

Comment: Final note: I agree with @winny. It's nearly impossible to troubleshoot an SMPS without an oscilloscope.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks Rohat, I am asking this question to understand correctly; IC1 is on the low side and connected to main with TR1. So isn't that isolated from the high side?  or there is another isolation for the output which you are talking about?

Comment: @EmreAnılTERZİOĞLU That's not the isolation. The isolation that I'm talking about is between the input and the output: There should be **no direct connection** between the input and the output circuitry. The IC is in the input (220V) side, but the IC's V- comes from the output's V-. There's a direct connection, so there's no isolation. This may or may not cause a problem. I can't tell by just looking at it.

Comment: @RohatKılıç,@winny I'll check and let you know. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @RohatKılıç [Could you please check this image](https://pasteboard.co/JkY10le.jpg) IC isn't on low(output) side?

Comment: @RohatKılıç The IC is on the secondary side and the gate drivers provide isolation to the primary. Difficult strategy to boot this...

Comment: @winny very good catch. I've never seen a 494 is used on the secondary side. Quite interesting but still useful. I was asking myself "How the f* the input's negative goes to V-?" :) So, you're right, Emre. The circuit has output isolated. However, I'm not sure that this info may help to solve the starting up problem. My previous suggestions still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.
The pads of one of the switching transistor were lifted. I repair these pads and SMPS worked fine.

Thanks for the support. @winny @RohatKılıç

[image: Lifted Pads]

Comment: Thanks for suppling and accepting the answer!